# CKEditor 4 h2 inside a

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I try to put this in the source code of CKEditor:

```
<a href="#"><h2>Title</h2></a>
```

It automatically transforms into this:

```
<h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
```

I tried setting `config.allowedContent = true;` in config.js, but it does not do anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below issues:

- https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9457
- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/514

CKEditor in general doesn't support transparent content model, but perhaps based on tip from second link, you will be able to achieve that result by changing the editor DTD.